# Anaconda environments packages update

Tags: python-2.7, server, anaconda, conda

Let's assume I perform a full anaconda installation as root that will be shared among all users.

a. On the *base* environment I install python2.7.12, matplotlib and numpy:

```
$ conda install python=2.7.12 matplotlib numpy
```

b. After a couple of months one of my users creates an environment:

```
$ conda install -n py27 python=2.7.12 matplotlib numpy
```

Let's assume that in the meanwhile a matplotlib and numpy were updated and are no longer on the same version.

My questions are:

1. will the versions of matplotlib and numpy installed in *a)* be automatically updated to the latest?
2. when the environment is created in *b)*, which versions of matplotlib and numpy are installed? the latest ones or the ones that were installed on the base environment in *a)*?

The reason I am asking this is because I attempting to implement a shared anaconda environment while minimizing the disk footprint. Basically, the reason is to avoid having for each user a different installation of anaconda and avoid having 20 different versions of matplotlib and numpy (among many others) taking up disk space.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a.) The versions of installed packages will not be updated automatically , packages are only updated when you explicitly issue the update commands with your package manager

b.) When a new environment is created and you try to install packages again , by default it will install the latest package (which may not match with whatever is present on your base environment)

Edit - I would like to comment that using a [requirements.txt](https://www.technologyscout.net/2017/11/how-to-install-dependencies-from-a-requirements-txt-file-with-conda/) file is a much better way to ensure everyone uses the same versions of the installed libraries.

or else you can make sure everyone mentions the version numbers along with the install command

eg : `pip install 'package_name==version_number'`

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to force the new environments to always use the versions installed on the base environment? (unless specified explicitly)

Comment: @jorgehumberto you could advice everyone to use the same requirements.txt (I've added a link) file for installing packages , but apart from that i can't think of anyway you could force a local os user to not install an updated version of a particular package on his local python env if he chooses to do that

Comment: thanks! Another alternative I thought about would be to clone a default environment, That would be similar, I guess? I that case, if I understood correctly, upon creation the packages on the new environments will be hard links to the packages in the cloned environment, correct? what if I update the packages on the cloned environment? will it break the hard links or update them as well? (assuming their versions were not set explicitly upon installation)

Comment: @jorgehumberto I fail to see how the alternative approach you proposed would in practice change anything compared to forcing everyone to just using the base environment.

Comment: Some of our users use environments to test and deploy some packages and would like the ability to create and manage their environments. However, if everyone deployed a different version of the same package, we might end up wasting a lot of space.

Comment: @jorgehumberto Okay so like i said - the situation you proposed is in theory going to accomplish the same results as having a base environment which everyone is forced to use. Even in this scenario users are free to create virtual environments and work on them if they so choose to. But there is one base environment which everyone has access to (i assume) everyone uses for testing code.

Comment: OK, thanks. And what would be the best approach? to use a base environment with both Python 2.7 and 3.5 or create independent environments, each with its python version?