# Solving environment: | Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages. The updating is eternal

Tags: python-3.x, package, conda, updates

I have Ubuntu 18.04.
I installed conda with python 2.7 some years ago. Finally I decided to pass to python 3.8
I create a new conda environment with python 3.8 and everything looked ok. When I tried to run a code by terminal, it printed:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

So I tip the command:

> conda install numpy

and the terminal started an endless work. It printed:

> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
> Solving environment: \
> The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
> The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

[...a series of link...]

> failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
> Solving environment: |
> Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
> This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.

Later I report all the terminal output.
Now it is examining conflicts with every packages of conda and it is working by hours.
Somebody knows what has happened?
Why it is not simply installing the packages?

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment? What happens if you try to install all the packages at once (which is the recommended way), using something like `conda create -n some-env python=3.8 numpy` ?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it.
I found another question with a similar situation:
[Anaconda environments packages update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51658582/anaconda-environments-packages-update)
So I retry to install it using the pip line and it worked:

> pip install numpy

I don't know why it doesn't work with the other way.

Comment: OMG! I spent about 3 hours trying various things and then about 45 minutes for this stupid "conda install" that never works. Tried out this solution and within seconds it installed! You have been a life saver!